# Default args in template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have something like this:

```
template<class T = unsigned = 64>
class X
{
};
```

Which basically says that if nothing is specified then unsigned should be the type and its value should be 64.

Answer (score 4):

Taken literally, it doesn't make sense. Explain what are you trying to do first.

Templates in C++ have three kind of parameters: 1) type parameters, 2) value (non-type)  parameters, 3) template parameters.

When you declare a parameter as `class T` it is a *type* parameter (first kind). It's "value" is actually a *type*. `unsigned`, for example. I.e. the "value" of `T` is `unsigned`.  `unsigned` will be substituted instead of `T` in this instantiation of `class X` template. Parameter `T` can't have any numerical value, like `64`.

Yet, you seem to be trying to create some kind of hybrid between kind 1 and kind 2 parameters. Firstly it is impossible. Secondly, there's no way to figure out what semantic meaning it could possibly have. Please, clarify your intent.

If you want to pass a numerical value, you have to create a template parameter of the second kind: a value parameter, as in

```
template <unsigned N = 64>
class X {
};
```

So, you need to decide first, what kind of template parameter you really need: a type parameter or a value parameter. Or maybe both. You haven't provided any details about your class `X`, so there's no way to guess what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  You could do something close though:

```
template < typename T = unsigned, T value = 64>
struct X{};
```

Edit: Dawned on me reading your other answer that there's something else you could do if you really wanted to:

```
template < unsigned N = 64 >
struct unsigned_
{
  typedef unsigned type;
  enum { value = N };
};

// alternative versions...int, long, etc...

template < typename T = unsigned_<64> >
struct X {};
```

This creates a bunch more work for the user though.  You could address some of that by using boost::enable_if and is_fundamental so that the user could supply a fundamental type without you breaking down because you're looking for T::type and T::value.

So, while there is no way to do exactly what you're looking for...depending on how ugly you want to get you could get pretty darn close from the user's perspective.